# Why is my button calling a function before actually clicking the button in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a button that changes a labels text, I feel like it should work fine, but the function that I assigned to the buttons command gets called before I even press the button, why is this happening and is there anything I can do to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def changeLabelText(my_label, new_text):
    my_label.config(text = new_text)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

label = tk.Label(root, text = "Old Text", font = ("font", 30))
label.grid(row = 0)

changeTextButton = tk.Button(root, text = "Click to change label text",
                             command = changeLabelText(label, "New Text"))
changeTextButton.grid(row = 1)

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda to pass variables to a call back.

```py
command = lambda: changeLabelText(label, "New Text"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing your function, you are calling it and passing what it returns.
You can pass functions without parameters by just leaving out the brackets

```
command = func
```

or you can use lambdas:

```
command = lambda: changeLabelText(label, "New Text")
```

Comment: This answer is same as the previous answer :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `lambda` for callback. It allows to create small, inline functions for the command parameter. The lambda function is an anonymous function in Python. You can read more about it: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp

It means you should change this parameter `command = changeLabelText(label, "New Text")` to this `command=lambda: changeLabelText(label, "New Text")`.

**Complete code:**

```
import tkinter as tk


def changeLabelText(my_label, new_text):
    my_label.config(text=new_text)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

label = tk.Label(root, text="Old Text", font=("font", 30))
label.grid(row=0)

changeTextButton = tk.Button(
    root, text="Click to change label text", command=lambda: changeLabelText(label, "New Text")
)
changeTextButton.grid(row=1)

tk.mainloop()
```

**"Before click" GUI:**

[image: Before]

**"After click" GUI:**

[image: After]